# Examples of Quot schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, examples, schemes

I'm studying Quot schemes, that I denote with $Quot_{N,X,P}$, with $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, $X \subset \mathbb{P}^d$ and $P \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$. So, I'm looking for explicit examples of Quot schemes. Could you give me as much as you can explicit examples of Quot schemes? 
On the net I found several papers about the construction of Quot schemes, but I can't find explicit examples in order to have a true understanding of these objects. For instance, how can I think of the Grassmannian as $Quot_{N,X,P}$ scheme? Are there different ways to do this? I'm sorry if this question isn't specific enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would some of the links provided by a Google search for "explicit examples of Quot schemes" be useful? (It's not my specialization).

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski I'm sorry, but unfortunately I can't find them!

Comment: http://msp.org/pjm/2007/231-2/pjm-v231-n2-p07-s.pdf: "...explicit...of quot schemes..." by Gustavsen at al

Comment: http://www.algant.eu/documents/theses/habibi.pdf: "Hilbert and Quot Schemes" by S.Habibi

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the answer to some of your questions in  N. Nitsure, [*Construction of Hilbert and Quot Schemes*, arXiv:math/0504590](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590).

Comment: Right, that's what a Google search for "explicit examples of Quot schemes" provides (and more).